# VBA - Store memory to check combination

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database with this pattern and with an average 1000 rows per province (I just need some province maybe 1 or 2):

```
Town Code: 3201 Locality Code: 010 Locality Desc: Kuta SubLocalityCode: 005 SubLocality Desc: Legian
```

and I want to validate my excel file which has the same columns as following:
Town Code, Locality Code, Locality Desc, SublocalityCode, SubLocality Desc

The code should validate whether the combination is right or not. For example `3202 010 Kuta 005 Seminyak` is wrong because 005 with 3201 as town code and 010 as locality should be Legian. And the wrong line will be colored red. Is there an efficient way regarding to the size of the database?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: This question is overly broad and looks more like a functional spec requesting a code-writing service. Please narrow down the question and include code samples, highlighting the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: Alex McMillan and Alex Bell, thanks for your response, I hope you guys don't mind since this is my first time. I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA lets you iterate through each row in a spreadsheet.

I assume you haven't set up your spreadsheet to markup the data as a `Table` so we'll have to use the traditional `Range` instead.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Validate()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range ' There is no `Cell` type in Excel, everything is a `Range`

    Set rng = Range("A2:E999")
    For Each row in rng.Rows

        For Each cell in row.Cells
            Select Case cell.Column
                Case 1 ' A: Town code
                    If Not TownCodeIsValid( cell.Value ) Then
                        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is not valid."
                    End If
                Case 2 ' B: Locality code
                    If Not LocalityCodeIsValid( cell.Value ) Then
                        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is not valid."
                    End If
                Case 3 ' C: Locality desc
                    If Not LocalityDescIsValid( cell.Value ) Then
                        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is not valid."
                    End If
                Case 4 ' D: Sublocality code
                    If Not SublocalityCodeIsValid( cell.Value ) Then
                        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is not valid."
                    End If
                Case 5 ' E: Sublocality desc
                    If Not SublocalityDescIsValid( cell.Value ) Then
                        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is not valid."
                    End If
            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function TownCodeIsValid(townCode As String) As Boolean
    ' Your validation code here
End Function

' and repeat for the other columns
```

Comment: Hi Dai, after I read it, It didn't really get the goal. My question is more like how to validate the combination. The combination allows same code with different description such as 5101 010 Melaya 001 Gilimanuk and 5102 010 Selemadeg  002 Antap still valid even both have 010 as locality code but different name because it's available in the database. According to your code, it's just find the code base on the database lets say, in case 2, 010 will be valid even the description is localitydesc from other province. Nevetheless, thank you for ur answer Dai!

Comment: @Anthony I cannot help you with implementing your exact validation rules, I just provided code to demonstrate how you would call-into your actual validation logic. If your actual question is how to perform the actual validation then you will need to re-word your question to make that clear.